# js поменять элементы массива первый с наименьшим

Tags: javascript

```js
const num = [ 30, 58, 50, 18, 65, 10, 46, 60, 14, 81, 82, 84, 17, 22, 51] // - этот диапазон задается рандомно, числа разные при каждом вызове.
const minIndex = Math.min.apply(null, num)
const arrResult = []
for (let n of num) {
  if (n === minIndex) {
    //arrResult.push(n) // 10
    arrResult.push(num[0], num[n])
  }
}
// Результат для этого массива [ 30, 82 ]
console.log(arrResult);
```

1. Как сделать, чтобы конечный массив имел тот же набор цифр, что и исходный?
2. Как поменять местами первый элемент и минимальный найденный?

Comment: Почемy Вы используете слово "Index" в названии переменной `minIndex`?

Comment: Чтобы знать что это минимальный индекс массива.

Comment: Вы совсем не понимаете, что делает `Math.min.apply(null, num)`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min

Comment: Возможно не совсем. Однако, находит минимальный индекс верно. arrResult.push(n) // 10

Comment: Верно? В какой реальности? Индекс минимального элемента в приведенном массиве - `5`.

Comment: Все, понял. Я путаю значение и индекс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так получилось решить:

```js
const filterResult = [
  (50), 30, 37, 32, 41, 27,
  24, 29, 44, (10), 31, 17,
  21, 33, 43
]
const num = filterResult
const minIndex = num.indexOf( Math.min.apply(null, num))
const firstIndex = num[0]

const arrResult = filterResult

  if (n === minIndex)
  arrResult[0] = arrResult[n], arrResult[n] = firstIndex


console.log(arrResult)
[
  (10), 30, 37, 32, 41, 27,
  24, 29, 44, (50), 31, 17,
  21, 33, 43
]
// где 50, поменялся местами с 10
```

Comment: Вам не нужен цикл. Достаточно поменять местами значения двух элементов массива.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Массив не нужен.

Comment: Я-то прав, а Вы продолжаете использовать слово "index" там, где не надо.